# How to cache ActiveXObject data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, caching, local-storage

I use the following code to retrieve data from SQL database:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring="Data Source=dbname;Initial Catalog=;User ID=userid;Password=pass;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
rs.Open("select * from db");
```

the query itself takes a few minutes. How can I cache the data received and perform the query only once per day (or by user request)?

The query works in Interner Exlorer 11 only, so looks like I can not use [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#Browser_compatibility). It looks like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) will work, but I don't understand how to store `rs` data there:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', rs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your rcordset to a javascript array like following.

```
var obj=[];
while (rs.EOF != true)   
  {  
  var row ={}
  row.Property1 = rs("Property1");
   //map othe columns
     obj.push(row);
    rs.MoveNext();  
  }
```

**You can't store object directly to LocalStorage as it only supports strings, so you need to covert it to string before storing it**. I also suggest you to append date along with the key, so that you can delete any previous day data and create new one if not exists.

```
localStorage.setItem('data_07_02_2018', JSON.stringify(obj));
```